# Deleting the facebook account from Settings

Tags: ios, facebook

is there any way to delete the facebook account from iPhone Device Settings programatically.
Please let me know how to implement this functionalioty.
Thnaks in advance.

Comment: No you can not open native Setting window from your application. so you can not delete Facebook account from iPhone setting programmatically.

Comment: You can not do this programatically.

Comment: Not possible unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to the delete the account programmatically, this would be a huge issue if you could.

Also start with iOS 5.1 you are no longer able to open the setting.app.

The only thing you can do is explain to your user how to delete there account